# asp.net scaffolding complex type using EF Code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, t4, scaffolding

I have 2 models looking like this:

```
public class Person
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address PersonsAddress { get; set; }

}

public class Address
{
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

now, when i scaffold the Person class like this: **scaffold controller Person -repository** and run the application and go to /persons, EF code first will create the following sql table for me:

- ID
- FirstName
- LastName
- Address_StreetName
- Address_City

This is all good, but when i look at the create view, the complex type address is not created by the scaffold template. The create view only has the 2 inputs for firstname and lastname.

So my question is, **how can i tell scaffold to also create the fields for streetname and city in the create, edit and list view?**

Do i have to edit the templates? And if yes, is it hard to do so? or recommended?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am have the same question. It seems like an oversite considering how code first manages to create the DB columns as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use T4 Templates to change how the wizard creates the view or you can override the EditorFor and Display for default templates